# Split out nested json/dictionary from Pandas dataframe into separate columns

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a problem that I cannot find a solution for - so here comes the request for assistance.

I receive an export from a DB that looks like this (of course, more than one line in reality):

```
"created_at","country","query_success","query_result"
"2022-08-18 08:38:38","Germany",True,"{""servers"": {""windows"": 0, ""linux"": 0}, ""workstations"": {""windows"": 0, ""mac"": 0}}"
```

I import it into Pandas in this way:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col='created_at', parse_dates=True)
```

Which turns it into this:

```
created_at          country query_success   query_result
2022-08-18 08:38:38 Germany True            {"servers": {"windows": 0, "linux": 0}, "workstations": {"windows": 0, "mac": 0}}
```

The problem I'm trying to resolve is the json/dictionary that populates the `query_result` column.

What I'd like to do would be to create and populate four new columns based on this data.

```
server_windows
server_linux
workstation_windows
workstation_mac
```

I've done quite some googling and have seen some solutions that uses the `ast` module but can't seem to get it right. It could potenially be due to the it being two nested dictionaries/json structures?

Thankful for any help/assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
import json

dfs = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(json.loads(d)) for d in df["query_result"]])
dfs = pd.DataFrame(dfs.values, columns=dfs.columns, index=df.index)

df = pd.concat([df, dfs], axis=1)
df.pop("query_result")
print(df.to_markdown())
```

Prints:

| created_at | country | query_success | servers.windows | servers.linux | workstations.windows | workstations.mac |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-18 08:38:38 | Germany | True | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |